# Isolating inner type of interface declared on object property with nonexplicit name?

Tags: typescript

The @serverless/typescript package as a type AWS that defines the serverless configuration object that you'd place in a serverless.ts file. Within that object there is a typed interface for the `functions` config of Lambdas. I want to extract just that config, which is not exported as a specific type in this library unfortunately.

The AWS type for functions look something like this

```
interface AWS {
  ...
  functions?: {
    [k: string]: { ...complex stuff in here... }
  }
}
```

The interface I want to extract is the type of `[k: string]`, but I can't find any way to refer to that segment of type.

In other words:

```
type AwsLambdaConfig = AWS['functions'][<what goes here>]
```

Is there any way to express the path that I want to extract?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQQOoGU4F84DMoQhwBEAAgM4CmUAbtQDaXnkD0MAnmEwMZTBgxiAbgBQIjlxQB3cgBkAhiABGAE3kBhCADtcwAOZwAvCgwBtYrgCuW7jGDbyxALosAVKakALefD0QmcJ7UlAD8Tq4soiwscLEAeiFAA) correctly replicate the situation you're asking about?

Comment: (I'm surprised we can't just use `[string]` at the end, but if my link above is right, we can't, which just goes to prove how much I still have to learn about TypeScript...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes that first example expresses the conundrum...

Comment: The problem seems to be that there is no way to refer to the value of `[k: string]`, which is not surprising in some ways since it's an unknown.

Comment: Yeah, but if it were just a simple index signature, `[string]` would work ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UDeAoK6oG0DWAuKAzsAE4CWAdgOYC6+RZVUAPlOQK4C2ARhMc1FwD2ggDYQAhuQDcKAL4yUoSFACaCWJnoUaMgPS6MAPQD8QA)). So there's something "special" about that AWS type. :-|

Comment: Ah, the "special"-ness was just that `AWS["functions"]` is an optional property. :-)

Comment: Oh interesting. Is it because functions is optional, i.e. `functions?: { ... }`? See here for example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UDeAoK6oG0DWAuKAzsAE4CWAdgOYC6+RZVUAPlOQK4C2ARhMc1FwD2ggDYQAhuQDcKAL4yUoSFACaCWJnoUaMgPS6MAPQD8KReGgAtdagxQAZm3IBjYKUHkCx-LbsYcdCTatIRBjCzs3Lz8QqIS0mgYsnJmSlZqiJaYAOSOLm4eBNnUmmE01Cj6RqZAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `AWS["functions"]` is optional, so you have to filter out the optionality before you can access the value type for its index signature via `[string]` at the end. We can do that via `Exclude`, so:

```
type AwsLambdaConfig = Exclude<AWS["functions"], undefined>[string];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQQOoGU4F84DMoQhwBEAAgM4CmUAbtQDaXnkD0MAnmEwMZTBgxiAbgBQIjlxQB3cgBkAhiABGAE3kBhCADtcwAOZwAvHACiAD270ArisoAeNOgDaxXFa3cYwbeWIBdABo4d1tdLUoVAD4nchg+LT0-URYWODSAPQB+IA)